# How to find a JSON object member based on a string value

Tags: jquery, jsonp, getjson, json

So let's assume I have a JSON file as such:

```
{ "store": {
"book": [ 
  { "category": "reference",
    "author": "Nigel Rees",
    "title": "Sayings of the Century",
    "price": 8.95
  },
  { "category": "fiction",
    "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
    "title": "Sword of Honour",
    "price": 12.99
  },
  { "category": "fiction",
    "author": "Herman Melville",
    "title": "Moby Dick",
    "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
    "price": 8.99
  },
  { "category": "fiction",
    "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
    "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
    "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
    "price": 22.99
  }
    ]
  }
}
```

What I want to do is grab a member of "book" and all of its string value pairs where title is "Sword of Honour". How can I do that with JQuery? The problem is that I don't know the index ID of the the member, if I did it would be trivial, i.e. store.book[1].XXX would give me the value of all of the sibling key value pairs I am looking for.

Any ideas on how I can do this with minimum code?

Comment: this is not json. this is pure js object. Json is a textual representation.

Comment: @RoyiNamir actually this _is_ legal JSON - the hint is the quotes around the keys.  However I suspect the OP doesn't need to know how to decode the JSON.

Comment: @Alnitak Json is a textual representation. `'{"a":3}'` not `{"a":3}`

Comment: Actually, I am just .ajax with jsonp as the datatype. So it's decoded JSON to my JS code. I just wanted to included textual representation of what I was dealing with to clarify my question.

Comment: @RoyiNamir no, a JSON body sent over HTTP does not require those enclosing quote marks.  You only need those if you're writing the JSON as a string literal.

Comment: @RoyiNamir the code above is perfectly valid JSON. Or else I suggest you edit the Wikipedia JSON article.

Comment: @RoyiNamir with all due respect, no, I'm not wrong.  A _raw_ JSON string does **not** have quotes around it.   A JS string literal (which might happen to contain JSON) **does**.

Comment: @Alnitak my bad. ( my misunderstanding) sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using array [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var matches = store.book.filter(function(val, index, array) {
    return val.title === 'Sword of Honour';
});
```

The result will be an array of all of the `book` elements that match the filter predicate.

NB: this is an ES5 method.  There's a shim on the linked MDN page for non-ES5 browsers.

Comment: where is the json converter ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir what JSON converter?  The OP has apparently already decoded the JSON.

Comment: I didnt understand it as if he already did that( and I still think he didnt)

Comment: Thank. That worked. But I managed to change my code to just grab the array index value for each element instead of the title and use that. This will still be useful in cases where it's impossible to get the index number.

Comment: To get other values console.log(matches[0].category); console.log(matches[0].author); console.log(matches[0].price);

Answer (score 0):

```
function returnMatchedbook(store) {
    for(var i = 0; i < store.book.length; i++) {
        if(book[i].title == 'Sword of Honour') {
            return book[i];
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: hey i updated the answer.it will return the matched book from the store